# I am using threads to do two things at the same time but the second thread stops the main thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I am using threads to do two things at the same time, the main thread is responsible for the program and the second thread is just to execute a function that function has a while loop that doesn't end unless the user presses a specific key on the keyboard.

```
// This function freezes an address value by assigning a value continuously
void SuperJump() {
    DWORD OffsetBaseAddress = 0x1C85FC;
    int value = 0;
    while (true) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD4)) {
            break;
        }
        Sleep(50);
        WriteProcessMemory(hHandle, (LPVOID)(BaseAddress + OffsetBaseAddress), &value, sizeof(value), NULL);
    }
}

int main() {
    DWORD OffsetBaseAddress;
    int value;

    while (true) {
        // ......
        // ......
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD3)) {
            std::thread th(&SuperJump);
            th.join();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is when the second thread starts the main thread (program) doesn't respond to any key press until the second thread is finished.
I want the main thread (program) keeps responding (working) during the second thread work, is that possible or is there another way to implement my idea?

Comment: `th.join()` immediately causes the main thread to wait for the new thread `th` to finish. It isn't clear to me how to fix this. It looks like you intend to allow multiple threads to wait for the same keystroke, and it isn't clear what the intended thread ownership scheme is here. You'll probably need a vector of `thread` but I'm not sure where you would clean up joinable threads.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: So, what is the benefit of threads (Multithreading) then, it must to stops the main thread to run another thread! Where is the simultaneous concept?

Comment: @LionKing what is benefit of create thread and after this wait on it exit ?

Comment: @RbMm: I am using threads just to implement two things at the same time not to stop the main thread to run the second thread (That is what I know about threads).

Comment: It doesn't need to stop the main thread, it executes asynchronously if you doesn't `join` the thread.

Comment: at first you not using threads. at second all your program logic is wrong. not need call `GetAsyncKeyState`. need use `SetWindowsHookExW` with `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` and do this from single thread

Comment: @LionKing There is no benefit to multithreading if the spawning thread always waits for the spawned thread immediately after creating it. But this is a usage error, not an inherent issue with threads. You have to figure out when the created thread needs to be joined, and join then. Joining immediately after creating a thread is always a usage error.

Comment: Can you explain why you are trying to read asynchronous keyboard input using two distinct threads?  This is generally considered a no-no since the keyboard is generally a single resource, and having threads in contention for that resource makes it hard to predict which thread will get what input.   The more usual approach is for the main thread to read input, and selectively pass it (e.g. via some messaging) to the threads that need input.

Comment: What you did was hire two workers so that you could get your job done faster. One worker was happily getting stuff done until you told the second worker to start the `SuperJump` task, then immediately told the first worker to stop working until the second worker finished (`join`). You hired two workers but refused to let them work at the same time. What is the benefit of hiring multiple workers (multithreading) then when you refuse to let them work at the same time?

Comment: @LionKing Have a look at [Creating Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-threads) which shows a normal thread usage.

Comment: The [library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) comes with full [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join). Why did you decide to not read it?

Answer (score 1):

```
          std::thread th(&SuperJump);
```

This creates a new execution thread.

```
          th.join();
```

`join()` pauses the calling execution thread until the other execution thread finishes running. That's what `join()` does, so after a new execution thread gets created the original thread immediately waits until it's finished, accomplishing nothing much by doing that.

There are two ways of making the execution threads run concurrently.

1. Don't join the execution thread immediately. The `std::thread` object itself must exist as long as the execution thread is running. The usual rules of C++ that govern scoping and lifetime can be used to control the lifetime of this thread object, when it gets created and destroyed. Use the existing lifetime and scoping rules to implement whatever actual duration of this execution thread you want to have, and only when the main execution thread wants this thread to stop, only then join and then destroy it.
2. Detach the new execution thread, and let it execute detached. The original thread object may be destroyed, but the calling thread no longer has any controls over joining a detached thread. Once detached it cannot be joined any more.

The expected behavior of your program is not very clear from the shown code. You'll need to figure out, and map out the semantics of your execution thread, when exactly it needs to start and stop, and implemented whichever approach you conclude will work best here.

Comment: What is the risk of using `Detach`?

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, by "risk"?

Comment: I heard a lot of people say don't use `Detach` when using threads, and until now I don't know why some people scare us of using that method.

Comment: Well, you should ask them what they meant by that. That's like saying "don't use a screwdriver". `detach()` is just a tool, like a screwdriver. It is necessary to understand how it works, and why it should be used. You have to do the same with a screwdriver. You have to understand that it is used to put in screws. But it's not the right tool for digging a hole. Same thing with `detach()`.

Comment: When you use `detatch()` there are basically two scenarios. The first is you somehow monitor the created thread using a separate mechanism and synchronize with it using that mechanism, in which case you should usually just use `join()` or `std::sync` instead. The other case is you do not synchronize with the created thread at all, in which case it is generally not possible to write code that both does useful work and also doesn't have some form of Undefined Behavior due to a race condition on some form of shared resource.

Comment: [continued] The problem with `detatch` is that it looks like it has a lot of use cases, but it is actually almost always a red flag hiding a bug and a design error all in one. Actual use cases are rare, except for trivial ones.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: So, the people who say it's dangerous are right?

Comment: @LionKing There is some debate about the subject, but I strongly agree with the opinion that `detatch` is almost always a mistake.